# QGIS:what does it do "snap gcp coordinates to background layers" in the Georeferencer plugin?

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, georeferencing

Maybe is too obvious, but I don't find any precise documentation about this checkbox in the georeferencer plugin.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It does allows you to use a point layer as a base for georeferencing. In order to use this option correctly, you must

a)load the point layer. It can be a shp or a text delimited layer

b)Set the snapping options to use the point layer and also the tolerance and units. I usually use 10-15 pixels.

c)Run the georeferencer and when adding a gcp, instead of typing the coordinates you can use the point layer by selcting "from map canvas" button. The coordinates of the selected point will be used as the coordinates of the gpc.

I like to use this way to georeference since it gives a more control to the process.
This video ["geoferencing with Qgis II"](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_Durq2vpe3k&list=TL22BaJro1xjo)

explain the process, It is in spanish, but you can see how it works

Comment: Thanks great answer great video, so actually an image referenced with this method is the same of an image georeferenced without this method. Is only a metter of how find points.

Answer (score 0):

It will do exactly what it says - when creating a Ground Control Point (GCP) from the map, it will snap to a vertex or line segment. I haven't tested, but assume it will respect the snapping options you have already set for the project.

Comment: I have raster layers as background so I thought it would georeference to them I thought was a relative georeferncing ... I would call it "snap gcp to vector layer" more clear...

Comment: Or "use gcp from vector layer"...:-)